# Twilio connection from Browser with REST API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I don't understand in what cases is convenient to use the Twilio REST API connection for make a call instead of Twilio.Device.connect(). When i make a connection from a browser (with Twilio Client), it isn't possible to use REST API connection, is it correct?
The REST API connection is only convenient for automatic call, where the caller isn't an human...is it correct?

Thank you

Comment: What is Twilio? "Twilio allows software developers to programmatically make and receive phone calls and send and receive text messages using its web service APIs." Now..., what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok, I have changed the question. There are two different method in Twilio for make a call, one with Twilio Client Library and another with REST API. If the caller is an human, I can use only the Twilio Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

There are lots of user cases for [initiating a call via the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls).  As you point out one is when you want an automated system to call a phone number to for example, play a recorded message or say some words via computer generated robot voice.

You might also want to use the REST API to initiate two calls to different phone numbers and then bridge those calls together. For example a professional services referral website may want to connect a potential customer to a specific service provider.

Another example would be if you wanted to initiate a customer service callback.  Rather than making your customers wait on hold for an agent, log their request for service and then call them back only when an agent becomes available.

The use cases go on and you can read about lots of them [on our website](https://www.twilio.com/voice/use-cases).

Hope that helps.